# Global variable changes its value when loop starts again

Tags: arduino-uno, variables

I have a problem with the global variable calibrationValue. It is initially set with the correct value and is also displayed correctly in the output. As soon as the loop function is restarted, the value of the variable is wrong, although it is not rewritten. Can someone help me please?
The following values ​​are printed in the image:

1. new AI value
2. wrong calibrationValue (!)
3. sumOfValues (needed for calculation of calibrationValue) correct
4. numValues (needed for calculation of calibrationValue) correct
5. Text and calibrationValue (correct!)

```
    int op_mode_Pin = 7;                      // Digital input Pin which transmittes the op_mode_Ardui
    int op_mode_Ardui;                        // Operator Mode of Arduino
    int returnValue1 = 12;                    // First digital return value for transmitting box weight
    int returnValue2 = 13;                    // Second digital return value for transmitting box weight  
    
    int sensorPin = A0;                       // Select the input pin for the potentiometer
    long weightValue = 0;                     // Variable to store the value from the sensor
    long calibrationValue = 0;                // Value which is filled in calibration progress
    int numValues = 50;                       // Number of taken values for calculating an average
    int thresBoxWeight = 300;                 // Weight for separating heavy and light boxes
    
    unsigned long sumOfValues;                // Sum of the taken values
    unsigned long aveOfValues;                // Average of the values
    
    char stringBuffer[30];                    // Buffer for combining string and variables
    
    void setup() {
      // Initiate serial communication to screen
      Serial.begin(9600);
    
      // Initiate some variables 
      //weightValue = 0;
      //calibrationValue = 0;
      //numValues = 50;
      //thresBoxWeight = 300;
      
      // Set the Input Pins for op_mode_Ardui
      pinMode(op_mode_Pin, INPUT);            // sets the digital pin 7 as input  
      
      // Set the Output Pins for Box declaration
      pinMode(returnValue1, OUTPUT);          // sets the digital pin 12 as output  
      pinMode(returnValue2, OUTPUT);          // sets the digital pin 13 as output
     
    }
    
    void loop() {
      Serial.println(analogRead(sensorPin));
      Serial.println(calibrationValue);
      // Reset of Sum and Average variables for next cycle
      sumOfValues = 0;
      aveOfValues = 0;
      op_mode_Ardui = digitalRead(op_mode_Pin);
      
      if (op_mode_Ardui == HIGH){
        for (int i=0; i<numValues; i++){
          weightValue = analogRead(sensorPin);                                                  // read the value from the sensor
          sumOfValues = sumOfValues + weightValue;                                              // Build the sum of all values
        }
        Serial.println(sumOfValues);
        Serial.println(numValues);
        
        calibrationValue = sumOfValues / numValues;
        sprintf(stringBuffer, "Calibration accomplished with value: %d", calibrationValue);     // Combine text and variable to output
        Serial.println(stringBuffer);                                                           // print text and variable to screen
        delay(3000);
      }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```cpp
sprintf(stringBuffer, "Calibration accomplished with value: %d", calibrationValue);
```

is a buffer overflow: the function `sprintf()` is writing a 40-byte
string into a 30-byte buffer. Whatever happens to lie in memory right
after the buffer will be overwritten by `sprintf()`. Apparently this
happened to be `calibrationValue`. You should use
`snprintf()` rather that `sprintf()`, as the former is designed to
prevent this kind of overflows.

Or better yet, stick with `Serial.print[ln]()`:

```cpp
Serial.print("Calibration accomplished with value: ");
Serial.println(calibrationValue);
```

**Edit**: You may notice that 13108 is the same as 0x3334, which on a
little endian architecture is stored in memory as 0x34 0x33. These are
the ASCII codes for "43", which is part of what `sprintf()` wrote past
the end of the buffer.

Comment: it's interesting that the buffer overflow in `stringBuffer` overwrites a variable defined further up in the file. In most compilers your globals get allocated in memory roughly in the order you declare them. (Optimizing compilers on 32 and 64 bit platforms might do some re-ordering to make variable sized structures fit in less memory while honoring word/longword/double alignment, but most Arduinos are 8 bit devices where there's no such thing as word alignment.)

Comment: It worked. I never thought that an overflow could affect global variables. Thank you.

Comment: On a real mode machine like an Arduino, a buffer overflow stomps whatever is in RAM. Global variables, data on the heap, whatever. And there's nothing stopping it.

Comment: @DuncanC: I don't know how the linker decides on the allocation order. I tried compiling the OP's code with avr-g++ 7.3.0, as shipped with the Arduino IDE 1.8.13, and the .bss section contains `timer0_fract`, `timer0_millis`, `timer0_overflow_count`, `stringBuffer`, `sumOfValues`, `calibrationValue` and `Serial`, in this order. If I remove `-flto` from the compiler's command line, I get a different allocation starting with `stringBuffer`, `aveOfValues` (which was optimized out with -flto), `sumOfValues`, `calibrationValue`